# Form couldn't direct to edit path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a form in the edit file under the related view folder. I want to direct this form to the editing route.

Here is my form,

```
<%= form_with(model: @trade, local: true) do |form| %>
  
  <%= form.button "Accept", name: "button_action", value: "accept" %>
  <%= form.button "Deny", name: "button_action", value: "decline" %>

<% end %>
```

My edit action in related controller,

```
  def edit
    @trade = Trade.find(params[:id])

    if params['button_action'] == 'accept'
      @trade.update(status: 1)
    else
      @trade.update(status: 2)
    end

    redirect_to root_path
  end
```

And my routes,

```
                          book_trades GET    /book/:book_id/trades(.:format)                                                     trades#index
                                      POST   /book/:book_id/trades(.:format)                                                     trades#create
                       new_book_trade GET    /book/:book_id/trades/new(.:format)                                                 trades#new
                      edit_book_trade GET    /book/:book_id/trades/:id/edit(.:format)                                            trades#edit
                           book_trade GET    /book/:book_id/trades/:id(.:format)                                                 trades#show
                                      PATCH  /book/:book_id/trades/:id(.:format)                                                 trades#update
                                      PUT    /book/:book_id/trades/:id(.:format)                                                 trades#update
                                      DELETE /book/:book_id/trades/:id(.:format)                                                 trades#destroy
```

But I couldn't direct and get no route matches error. I'm new to ruby and programming, what's the point I'm missing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The edit method is for rendering the form. The form action will send a PUT request to the update method.

You need to keep the move the logic in the `edit` method to the `update` method